# мусор в массиве

Tags: c, указатели, память, динамические-массивы

Доброго времени суток. Возникла следующая проблема. Имеется следующий код:

```
int leng[10] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
int *res;

res = (int*)malloc(8*sizeof(int)); // на 8 не обращайте внимание
memset(res, 0 , 8);

res = func(leng, 10, 8);
// ...
```

Вот код самой функции `func`:

```
static int* func(int *arr, int len, int size)
{
    int *arrTemp;
    int i = 0;

    arrTemp = (int*)malloc(len* sizeof(int));
    memset(arrTemp , 0, len);

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
      printf("%d ", *(arrtemp + i));

// ...
}
```

На экране при печати первые три элемента как и в исходном массиве, в остальных же мусор. Помогите разобраться, почему?

Comment: Не нужно исправлять код в вопросе на рабочий, после того, как вам дали ответ и указали на ошибки. Иначе, люди которые придут сюда позже, не поймут в чём изначально была проблема.

Comment: Спасибо большое за замечание! Учту.

Answer (score 3):

`memset` устанавливает указанное количество **байт**. Хотите обнулять все - передавайте полный размер, как в `malloc`:

```
arrTemp = (int*)malloc(len* sizeof(int));
memset(arrTemp , 0, len* sizeof(int));
```

переданный в `func` указатель вы вообще нигде не используете. Так что выводите вы нули и немножко мусора.

Если, конечно, вы написали тот код, что на самом деле. В чем позвольте усомниться - например, в

```
for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
```

что такое `length`? Этой переменной у вас нет.

Comment: Спасибо большое за замечание! `length` исправил (это из старого файла было).

Comment: ответ тогда на вопрос "почему там мусор?" - потому что нужно указывать везде `size * sizeof (int)` - байт указывать? (size в данном случае абстрактная константа).

Comment: `calloc()` = `x = malloc(n * sizeof(*x)); memset(x, 0, ...);`

Answer (score 2):

Всё работает абсолютно нормально:

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <stdlib.h>
     #include <string.h>

     static int* func(int *arr, int len, int size) {
         int *arrTemp;
         int i = 0;

         arrTemp = (int*)malloc(len* sizeof(int));
         memset(arrTemp , 0, len * sizeof(int));
         memcpy(arrTemp, arr, len * sizeof(int));
         for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
           printf("%d ", *(arrTemp + i));

        return arrTemp; }

     int main () {  int leng[10] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};  int    *res;

        res = (int*)malloc(8*sizeof(int)); // на 8 не обращайте внимание
        memset(res, 0 , 8*sizeof(int));

        res = func(leng, 10, 8); 
}
```

Comment: Просто топикстартер зачем-то исправил код в вопросе на рабочий, после того, как получил ответ. Откатил исправления кода в вопросе.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Да дело ко сну уже было, поэтому, видимо, по ошибке исправления ненужные внёс :)